# Django Rest Framework serializer is printing tuples instead of json

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've got the following serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for Product object """

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'slug', 'description', 'image', 'price', 'active',]
```

and the following test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework import status

from .factories import ProductFactory
from .models import Product
from .serializer import ProductSerializer

PRODUCTS_URL = reverse('product-list')

def create_product(**params):
    """ Helper function to create a new product """
    return Product.objects.create(**params)

class PublicProductApiTests(TestCase):
    """
    Test the public products' API
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    
    def test_only_active_products_are_returned(self):

        ProductFactory.create_batch(2)
        
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)

        print(serializer.data)
```

When I print `serializer.data` on the screen, I'm getting:

> [OrderedDict([('name', 'Shane Fields'), ('slug', 'shane-fields'),
> ('description', 'Chance yourself conference.'), ('image',
> '/media/position/school.tiff'), ('price', '2.66'), ('active',
> False)]), OrderedDict([('name', 'Michael Hall'), ('slug',
> 'michael-hall'), ('description', 'Office city material room character
> number cause way.'), ('image', '/media/American/know.txt'), ('price',
> '-90244357.41'), ('active', True)])]

after passing the queryset to the serializer and printing its data, isn't supposed to print in JSON format? what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any problem with your solution because serializer data always returns an ordered dict type of serialized data. Viewsets of `rest_framework` will handle it for you and reformat this object to json type (for example when you have `return Response(serializer.data)` it will change all input data format to json format). There are lots of ways if you want to see the json format of your data, for instance:

```
import json

data = json.dumps(serializer.data)

print(data)  # which will print json format of your data
```

or you can use `print(dict(serializer.data[0])` or any other index to change the format of it to dictionary type. But if you want to test your endpoints you should use rest API test cases and then assert your response in your test cases. For more information you can use [rest framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/) about it's builtin test cases.

Comment: quick question here. When I return data from my view I'm returning it as `return Response(serializer.data)` isn't that supposed to be enough to return it as JSON? or when returning data, do I have to do `return Response(json.dumps(serializer.data))`?

Comment: If you want to test your API response use `TestCase` builtin methods. For example you can use `self.assertContains(result, "abcd")` (here result is the return value of your API) and you don't need to convert it to `json` format. Use `assertContains` when you want to know that your API response includes your desired data. For more examples and test cases you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/ (Django docs about different test cases).